# Search multiple arrays for a string and then set a var - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looking to set a variable based on which array a string exists in.

For example:

```
var primary   = ["red", blue", "yellow"];
var secondary = ["orange", "purple", "green"];
```

Then check for "purple" and return that it is in the "secondary" array and assign it to a variable to use later.

jQuery or Javascript is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you wanted to assign to a variable, so I just used alerts to illustrate the result

```
var plen = primary.length;

var idx = $.inArray( 'purple', primary.concat( secondary ) );

if( idx === -1 ) {
    alert( 'not found' );
} else if( idx < plen ) {
    alert( idx + ' in primary' );
} else {
    alert( (idx - plen) + ' in secondary' );
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/S9WL6/

---

Then you can make it into a reusable function:

```
function inArrays( val, arr1, arr2 ) {
    var len1 = arr1.length;

    var idx = $.inArray( val, arr1.concat( arr2 ) );

    var ret = {index:idx,array:null};

    if( idx > -1 ) {
        if( idx < len1 ) {
            ret.array = arr1;
        } else {
            ret.array = arr2;
            ret.index -= len1;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

inArrays( 'purple', primary, secondary );
```

---

**EDIT:** Or make it into a function that can accept a variable number of Arrays.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5pZUQ/

```
var first = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];
var second = ["orange", "purple", "green"];
var third = ["brown", "black", "white"];

function inArrays(val) {
    var arrays = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    var len = 0;
    var i = 0;

    var idx = $.inArray(val, [].concat.apply([], arrays));

    var ret = {
        index: idx,
        array: null
    };

    if (idx > -1) {
        do {
            ret.array = arrays[i];
            ret.index = idx - len;
            len += arrays[i].length;
            i++;
        } while (idx >= len)       
    }
    return ret;
}

console.log( inArrays('white', first, second, third) );
```

Comment: If there are more than two arrays how does that affect the line:

    var idx = $.inArray( 'purple', arr1.concat( arr2 ) );

Comment: @ejay: I just updated with a solution that can handle a variable number of Arrays.

Comment: @patrick dw Thanks. It seems to recognize the index in the array but I'm not getting the correct array identifier (constant array of 3). My goal is to set a var based on which array the string is in.    Object { index=2, array=[3]}

Comment: @ejay: If you mean that the `array` property of the object returned should be the 1-based index number of the arrays in which the result was found, then just change this: `ret.array = arrays[i];` to this `ret.array = i+1;`.

Comment: @patrick dw That seems to do the trick.  Now a silly question that I'm not sure what terms to search for in order to learn how to do it...  How do I use the returned object and remove the array value and then assign it to a variable?

Comment: @ejay: You can just do `var array_index = obj.array;`. Or, if you're not interested in the actual index number of the item in the Array, but instead just the number showing which array it was in, we could skip the object altogether in the `inArrays` function, and have it *just* return that single index.

Comment: var some_var =( inArrays('white', first, second, third) ).array;

Is this the best method?

Comment: @ejay: That would be fine. If you want a solution that simply does multiple `inArray` calls on each array, you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/hJrAA/ I also changed it to only return the index representing the array in which the value was found.

Comment: [You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in JavaScript engines (V8 for example). Instead, try constructing a new array by iterating through the arguments object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)