# Query if string is in any one of a set of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function written in JQuery. I have some arrays, like so:

```
var array1 = ["pink","yellow","green","red"],
    array2 = ["peony","violet","rose","daisy"],
    array3 = ["dalmation","kelpie","shepard","dachshund"],
```

I have a value from an input, called

```
$query
```

I would like to find out if the value of $query is equal to the value of any of the elements of any of the 3 arrays. If yes, I would like to know which array it is. An index number (ie 0 for array1, 1 for array2) would work fine.

This JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hJrAA/ from this StackOverflow question [Search multiple arrays for a string and then set a var - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109708/search-multiple-arrays-for-a-string-and-then-set-a-var-jquery) is tantalising, but no matter what I change the value of the input query to,

```
 console.log(inArrays('red', first, second, third));
```

(where 'red' is the query) it always returns the same value (2).

Can anyone suggest a way to modify that code so that it returns a reference to the specific array that the query was found in?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/  seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted to return the index of the first array that was found I would do this:

```
function inArrays(val) {
    var arrays = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    var idx = -1;
    var i = 0;

    while (i < arrays.length) {
        if ($.inArray(val, arrays[i]) > -1) {
            return i; // Breaks out of the loop as soon as a match is found             
        }
        i++;
    }
    return idx;
}
```

Two things are different here from your fiddle

1. $.inArray is returning an index, not True or False, so if it's found the index will be >= 0.  If an index is not found it will be -1.
2. I do a `return i` instead of setting the index and continuing.  This not only breaks out of the loop earlier, it will return the index of the first match.  Your original code always will return the last match.

Comment: Bingo! That's what I wanted. Thank you for the explanation of what you changed, that is very helpful to understanding what is going on in there.

Comment: Here's an updated JSFiddle with your code, in case it is useful to future seekers: http://jsfiddle.net/bfKsZ/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf()
>   method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the
>   first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.
>
> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 ==
>   false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value
>   within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than)
>   -1.

```
if ($.inArray(val, arrays[i]) > -1)
```